# Querying into PostgreSQL return a NoneType

Tags: mysql, postgresql

After creating a user in my database in my app deployed on Heroku, I get into the log page if successful. When I try to log, it does the following query :

```
result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", [username])
```

Yet it gives me the following error :

```
018-07-03T15:02:47.167067+00:00 app[web.1]: File "app.py", line 140, in login
2018-07-03T15:02:47.167069+00:00 app[web.1]: if result > 0:
2018-07-03T15:02:47.167071+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Yet, the registration query was successful and I'm pretty sure I provided the right credentials. Here is the code involved:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get Form Fields
        username = request.form['username']
        password_candidate = request.form['password']

        # Create cursor
        #cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur = conn.cursor()

        # Get user by username
        result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", [username])

        if result > 0:
            # Get stored hash
            data = cur.fetchone()
            password = data['password']

            # Compare Passwords
            if sha256_crypt.verify(password_candidate, password):
                # Passed
                session['logged_in'] = True
                session['username'] = username

                flash('You are now logged in', 'success')
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
            else:
                error = 'Invalid login'
                return render_template('login.html', error=error)
            # Close connection
            cur.close()
        else:
            error = 'Username not found'
            return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Maybe this is because this query used to be for a MySQL database

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like that query would return an integer.

Perhaps you want to select `COUNT(*)` rather than `*` to get the number of matching rows.

Comment: I added a little code. It's not likely to create problems on the stuff that I test afterwards as in data? The command worked well with MySQL

Comment: Huh? You removed the old code, and the new one doesn't seem to be connected to the question.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed a few lines in the version before. In this last version there is not only the query into the PostreSQL database but also the password test. If I did a count would I still be able to test the password provided ?

Comment: Maybe you can find a better way to test for an empty result set.